# re.findall and regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7, findall

I need to get the names of something like this *content*:

```
<p>
<a name="blu" title="blu"></a>orense
</p>
<p>
<a name="bla" title="bla"></a>toledo
</p>
<p>
<a name="blo" title="blo"></a>sevilla
</p>
```

but with this code:

```
names = []
matches = re.findall(r'''<a\stitle="(?P<title>[^">]+)"\sname="(?P<name>[^">]+)"></a>''',content, re.VERBOSE)
for (title, name) in matches:
    if title == name:
        names.append(title)
return names
```

...I get names=[ ]; what is wrong?.  Thanks.

Comment: About your *blasphematory* need to use regex for parsing Html, read the first answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 4):

Uh, well obviously, in your sample text, `name` comes before `title`, and in your regex, `title` is expected before `name`. This is precisely the reason (or one of them) why you should be using an HTML parser instead. Try [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for example.

If you insist on regex, just turn the parameters around (and make sure that you'll never get those attributes in a different order, and never any other attributes than those):

```
names = []
matches = re.findall(r'''<a\sname="(?P<name>[^">]+)"\stitle="(?P<title>[^">]+)"></a>''',content, re.VERBOSE)
for (name, title) in matches:
    if title == name:
        names.append(title)
```

Result:

```
>>> names
['blu', 'bla', 'blo']
```

Comment: yes, beautifulsoup is more sure by far, but it is inherited code and I didn't find why the regex was wrong. Trees prevented me from seeing the forest. Thanks a lot.